# split a java collection into sub collections based on an object property

Tags: java, collections

I have a List of MyObjects ... MyObject{ int id,String name}. Now I want to split the list into sublists that have identical "id" values. Can anyone suggest an efficient approach for doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// create the thing to store the sub lists
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> subs = new HashMap<Integer, List<MyObject>>();

// iterate through your objects
for(MyObject o : list){

    // fetch the list for this object's id
    List<MyObject> temp = subs.get(o.getId());

    if(temp == null){
        // if the list is null we haven't seen an
        // object with this id before, so create 
        // a new list
        temp = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

        // and add it to the map
        subs.put(o.getId(), temp);
    }

    // whether we got the list from the map
    // or made a new one we need to add our
    // object.
    temp.add(o);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

If you are using JDK 1.8, you can use an elegant solution like:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> myObjectsPerId =
    myObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId));
```

Comment: I wish I could smash that LIKE button for your answer a million times. A very elegant one liner that has so much going on under the hood.

Answer (score 8):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
ListMultimap<Integer, MyObject> myObjectsById = Multimaps.index(myObjects,
    new Function<MyObject, Integer>() {
      public Integer apply(MyObject myObject) {
        return myObject.id;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Or, when using Java 8: ListMultimap<Integer, MyObject> myObjectsById = Multimaps.index(myObjects, MyObject::getId);  But then you might as well skip Guava altogether and use Damien O'Reilly's answer

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the elements, check their `id` values, and place them in a `Hashtable` with `id` as the key. That's O(N), which is as efficient as you're going to get.

Comment: @Kirk - That depends on how the OP would be using it. With such a trivial object it might be convenient to have `name` be the value, however in many situations it would make more sense to have the value be the object itself: it's not a question you can answer without more context.

Answer (score 2):

Using JDK 1.8:

```
List<MyObject> objects= new ArrayList();
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> obejctMap = new HashMap();
objects.stream().map(MyObject::getId).distinct().forEach(id -> obejctMap .put(id,
              objects.stream().filter(object -> id.equals(object.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list=new ArrayList<MyObject>();
//fill Objects..
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<MyObject>> hash=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<MyObject>>();
for(MyObject elem:list)//iterate the list
{
ArrayList<MyObject> tmp=null; //temporary variable 
if((tmp=hash.get(elem.getId()))==null) // check if id already present in map
 {
  tmp=new ArrayList<MyObject>();   
  hash.put(elem.getId(),tmp); //if not put a new array list
 }
names.add(elem); //if present add the name to arraylist
}
```

Comment: names never becomes non-null in this solution in the case that you have to add a new ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `Collectors.groupingBy` solution using [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method, which is also available starting from Java 8:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> res = new HashMap<>();
for (MyObject obj : myObjects) {
  res.computeIfAbsent(obj.getId(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(obj);
}
```