# In Java, how to split an array or list by some property or value?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

If there is an array or list that contains Foo objects, and I want to split the collection based on the property Foo.bar, is there a quick way to do it in Java besides using a map and traversing the collection?

For example, say the list looks like:

1. Foo.bar = 1
2. Foo.bar = 1
3. Foo.bar = 2
4. Foo.bar = 3
5. Foo.bar = 3
6. Foo.bar = 4

The list will be split into 4 different lists because there are 4 distinct values of bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [split a java collection into sub collections based on a object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836621/split-a-java-collection-into-sub-collections-based-on-a-object-property)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921003/split-java-arraylist-by-properties-of-contained-objects

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/491631/java/java/easy-split-Arraylist-multiple-lists

Comment: Specifically asked for a method w/o using a map -_-

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is Treeset where you can add different values. but also you have override equals method.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject){
   Foo f = (Foo) anObject;
   return f.bar==this.bar
}
```